# R function to test significance of within group means

Tags: r

my question is  about this fictitious data. I would like to test if there is significant difference  among the three means (V1, V2 and V3) considered together. In R And  test if the average of v1 is significantly different from V2.

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
V1<- c(50,  42, 58, 56, 25, 85, 12, 23, 89, 52)
V2<- c(65,  63, 52, 45, 89, 58, 74, 51, 26, 25)
V3<- c(68,  95, 62, 14, 12, 25, 48, 56, 32, 57)
sex <- c("F","F","F","F","F","M","F","F","M","M")
data<- data.frame(id,V1,V2,V3,sex)
```

I tried using ANOVA but was not successful

Comment: *How* did you try using ANOVA?

Comment: i've tried many ways from online suggestions, the latest one i've tried is this aov(formula = id~V1 + V2+V1, data=data)

Comment: Okay, what is wrong with that? This question is a little vague. Please edit your question and put that code in it as well as why you think that its results are incorrect or confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use anova(), you need to wrap your formula using lm().

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
V1<- c(50,  42, 58, 56, 25, 85, 12, 23, 89, 52)
V2<- c(65,  63, 52, 45, 89, 58, 74, 51, 26, 25)
V3<- c(68,  95, 62, 14, 12, 25, 48, 56, 32, 57)
sex <- c("F","F","F","F","F","M","F","F","M","M")
data<- data.frame(id,V1,V2,V3,sex) 
anova(lm(id ~ V1 + V2 + V3, data = data))
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: id
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value   Pr(>F)  
 V1         1  0.438  0.4382   0.0751  0.79330  
 V2         1 29.750 29.7497   5.0959  0.06478 .
 V3         1 17.285 17.2846   2.9607  0.13610  
 Residuals  6 35.028  5.8379                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```